# How do I send ether and data from a smart contract to an EOA?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to create a "real" transaction from inside a smart contract to an EOA. This is so that I can attach data/input_data to send to it.

I've read several resources on this but I've come to contradictory information: some say it's impossible, some say that call() can achieve this. I've been testing multiple methods and have not come to see that it is possible.

Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.6;

contract Simple {
    uint32 value;
    constructor() payable {
        // Contract is initialized with 0.5 ether
        value = 22;
    }

    function foo() public {
        require(address(this).balance >= 0.1 ether);
        // Along with transfering ether, I want to send some data to the EOA,
        // for example, whichever value is in the variable "value"
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(0.1 ether);
    }
}
```

On a "normal" transaction, it is possible to set the field "input data" (normally used to make function calls when sending a transaction to a smart contract), which allows us to send data on a transaction from an EOA to another EOA. I was able to achieve this already.

But, from my understanding, contracts "can't" create transactions; they only create "internal transactions" (informal name) that are associated with the "parent transaction" (transaction that called the contract in the first place) and therefore don't have the data field. But they're able to call another contract on the network, so I assume they're able to send some data along the network, right?

Furthermore, this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17273/how-do-i-add-data-to-a-send-transaction-in-solidity) seems to imply that the low level call() method is able to achieve this. I've tried multiple approaches but have not been able to reproduce the wanted behaviour.

```
msg.sender.call{value: 0.1 ether}("data", value); // Doesn't work
msg.sender.call{value: 0.1 ether}(value); // Doesn't work
msg.sender.call{value: 0.1 ether}(abi.encodeWithSignature(value)) // Doesn't work
```

At some point, I did find my message on a block's "extra data", but from my understanding, this was written there by the miner for some reason.

So, to sum it up, is it possible to, from a contract, send ether + message to an EOA account? How would I achieve this?

Edit: Fixed the function name, which was a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 3):

```
function msg() public {
```

This function name is a bit problematic, because you're overriding the global `msg` variable, and can't use the `msg.sender`.

So I changed the function name to generic `foo()`.

```
function foo() public {
```

---

```
msg.sender.call{value: 0.1 ether}
```

Since Solidity 0.8, an `address` is not `payable` by default (source: [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/080-breaking-changes.html#new-restrictions)). So if you want to send them the native currency (in case of Ethereum, that's ETH), you need to cast the `address` to `payable` first.

```
payable(msg.sender).call{value: 0.1 ether}
```

---

Finally to the data sending part.

> *At some point, I did find my message on a block's "extra data", but from my understanding, this was written there by the miner for some reason.*

I'm not exactly sure, but it seems like you stumbled upon the correct field, which is simply the `data` field of the raw transaction, and the blockchain explorer probably named it "extra data". The `data` field is not filled by the miner, but by the transaction creator.

Since you're sending an integer, and the `data` field is `bytes` (array of bytes), you need to encode it to bytes. In your case:

```
abi.encode(value)
```

---

To you put it all together:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.6;

contract Simple {
    uint value;
    constructor() payable {
        value = 22;
    }

    function foo() public {
        require(address(this).balance >= 0.1 ether);
        payable(msg.sender).call{value: 0.1 ether}(abi.encode(value));
    }
}
```

When you execute the `foo()` function (and the contract has enough funds), it will create an **internal transaction** (some blockchain explorers might use a different name) to the `msg.sender` with value `0.1 ether` and the **decimal** `22` encoded as **hex** `16` in the `data` field.

Comment: The function name was a mistake on my end when writing a simple example. I've edited the OP to refer to it as foo too.
With the payable aspect, "call" can be called on any type of address and it will send ether regardless of wheter the address is payable or not, if specified.
Continues >>>

Comment: >>> And as I specified on my question, I didn't find this "data" field on the transaction; I found it on the transaction's block's data. As in, the actual block, not the transaction. From what I've read anyone can write data here, and it's usually used by miners to log their mining. For example, check https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/10738162. I ran your exact contract here (transaction https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x34aec5dbdbd9984461c8079f90e066f058f5bd9d65793f7d75b54abbabc14d0d ). The data - 0x16 - is nowhere to be found, not even the receipt.

Comment: Here's the internal transaction produced by the low-level `call` - [link](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x34aec5dbdbd9984461c8079f90e066f058f5bd9d65793f7d75b54abbabc14d0d#internal). The blockchain explorer doesn't show the `data` field of this internal call, but you can verify it for example by triggering the internal call to a contract that saves the recieved `msg.data` in the `fallback` function.

Comment: And how would I go about verifying that msg.data on a EOA when the transaction is made to a EOA?

Comment: You can debug the transaction, for example using [Truffle debug](https://www.trufflesuite.com/blog/announcing-full-portable-solidity-debugger). But I'm not aware of any blockchain explorer that would display the `data` field of an **internal** transaction (no matter if the receiver is a contract or an EOA).

Comment: I will have to take a deeper look at this, but is this possible to be done programatically in a production environment? From my limited knowledge, Truffle is more like a developing aid tool for developing and testing in a local test network. Can this data field from the internal transaction be aquired in, for example, python, if the transaction is made on the main network?

Comment: You can use a debugger to debug production transactions as well... An internal transaction is just a part of the main transaction, and is not available by itself over the RPC protocol. Which means it's not available in the regular Python/JS/<whatever language> RPC wrapper libraries (such as web3) without using any debug tools. Even blockchain explorers such as Etherscan use debug tools (in their case it's probably on the node level) to parse out internal transactions and store them in a dedicated DB, so it's easier to display them for users.

Comment: @PedroPerpétua Actually what is your intention? Why do you want to send `data` to an EOA? Maybe there's a more fitting or a more straightforward way to achieve your goal.

Comment: I'm trying to have a wallet receive a transaction with data asynchronously. As in, something external triggers a transaction that sends funds and a message to someone's wallet where that someone would get the message. I don't know if it's explained too well. I need a user to get both funds and some data regarding those funds at the same time.

Comment: Most wallet apps don't support reading the `data` field in the main transaction (or even decoding the field value to a string). And as you can see above, it's even more complicated to read it in the internal transaction... So my recommendation instead, is to emit an **event** as a part of the transaction, where any off-chain app can read the event data much more easily than debugging the internal transaction. Example Solidity code: `emit MyEvent('custom string'); payable(msg.sender).transfer(0.1 ether);`